# Does $||x|| < c$ imply $|x_i| < c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Given an $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and an arbitrary norm $||\cdot||$

Does $||x|| < c$ imply $|x_i| < c$ for some $c > 0$?

Answer (score 5):

No. Chose the norm $\|\cdot\|_\text{me}$ defined by $\|x\|_\text{me} :=\frac12 \|x\|_\infty$. You can easily check that this is in fact a norm, but $\|2\cdot e_1\|_\text{me} = 1$.

There is however the following theorem (a special case of the fact that all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent):

> For any norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb R^n$ there are constants $c$ and $C$ depending on the norm such that
>   $$\|x\| < 1 \Rightarrow \|x\|_\infty < C\\
> \|x\|_\infty < c \Rightarrow \|x\| < 1$$
>   Or equivalently
>   $$\frac1C\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\| \le \frac1c\|x\|_\infty$$